# Sandboxie or an alternative to macOS

Tags: macos, macos-bigsur

I use Sandboxie on Windows, is there such a program for Macbook Pro M1? I can't find anything. I want the program for safe internet browsing.
Thank you.

Comment: Mac apps are already sandboxed, but not in the same way. Simplest fully-secured sandbox is a VM.

Answer (score 1):

The only true equivalent of Sandboxie on MacOS is using a VM.

The built-in
[App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)
can restrict access to sensitive resources on a per-app basis

You may also use Time Machine to return the computer to its state before
you installed or used a new application.

You may use [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)
to clean up after an installed app, but it cannot undo modifications
done by that application.